# Crystal Report filtered by ID

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, crystal-reports, report

i am a beginner with Crystal Report and i need some help.

I am using C# .NET, with SQL Server 2012. I need to generate a printing report from a button click. But i need the data in the report to be selected only from one ID .

example:

(table in SQL)

---

ID     Name        Details

1      John           C#

2      Peter          VB

---

So i need a button, that will get the ID from a parameter declared earlier in the page (example ID=2). When i click the button, i need to get the data for printing, ( 2, Peter, VB).  If the ID=1, i need (1, John, C#).

Answer (score 0):

and what is the problem ? Get data from database by ID, then assign it to report data source